# Listening for new messages from IRC

Tags: javascript, irc

Is there a practical way to have a setup such that the browser could listen for new messages from a specified channel on an IRC server and change the title to "UserX messaged you!" when it happens?

If it is helpful, the IRC channel in question is hosted on Rizon.net.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your code that listens for new messages (AJAX, Sockets, Polling, whatever..), this would be the code that changes the title when that happens:

```
document.title = "UserX messaged you!"
```

You can pop this code into your console to check it out yourself.

Usually, chat websites (like Facebook), store the previous value and periodically alternate the value. Once the message gained attention, a script should revert it to the previous value.

Comment: The "listening" aspect is the one I am trying to figure out. Do you know a specific tool I should use for that?

Comment: @kyothine then you should change your question and focus more on the listening rather than the changing. Also, state what code and service are you using for the IRC.